# Find all the div tags find class = "post-" followed by some numbers?

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I want to find all the div tags with class = "post-some number some text "
There are multiple div tags e.g.

```
<div class="post-3562 some text">
<div class="post-some text">
<div class="post-some text">
<div class="post-1324 some text">
<div class="post-4540 some text">
<div class="post-some text">
<div class="post-1122 some text">
```

I only want to get those div tags with class="post-some number"

Currently I have written this:

```
allPostsDiv = soup.find_all("div", class_= "post")
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want to do? May be using regular expressions would help?
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: `(?<=\<div class=)"post-\d+ some text"(?=\>)`..you can use this

Answer (score 3):

You can pass in a regular expression as the value of your `class_` parameter, like so:

```
soup.find_all(name='div', class_=re.compile(r'^post-\d+$'))
```

Full Program:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup('''
<root>
<div class="post-3562 some text"/>
<xdiv class="post-9999 some text"/>
<div class="post-some text"/>
<div class="post-some text"/>
<div class="post-1324some text"/>
<div class="some post-4540 text"/>
<div class="post-some text"/>
<div class="some text post-1122"/>
</root>''', 'html.parser')

for div in soup.find_all(name='div', class_=re.compile(r'^post-\d+$')):
    print div
```

Result:

```
<div class="post-3562 some text"></div>
<div class="some post-4540 text"></div>
<div class="some text post-1122"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The following Regex will match your test cases:

```
/<div +class= *"post-\d+.*>/g
```

Regex Tester link: https://regex101.com/r/cX1qZ7/1